# Logback terminal log viewer

Tags: logging, terminal, slf4j, logback

I am using Logback with SLF4J, and I am interested is there any text-based (terminal, console) log viewer for logs produced by this logger?  Main features I need is filtering based on error level, time and such.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never heard to text-based log viewers... I you really need something in a console, I suggest implementing your own scripts based on grep (or any scripting language)...

Comment: That's a shame there is nothing like that, because servers and other software usually logs into files. Nevertheless, I already did something similar, came up with a set of commands to filter out the file in a combination with tail. It does the job.